# Django ORM column arithmetic

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a model in django having arrival_date, arrival_time and duration as columns. I require to filter the objects for which the arrival_date is today, and arrival_time + duration is not greater than current time.

```
    q1 = Q(arrival_date=current_date)
    q2 = Q(arrival_time__lte=current_time - timedelta(minutes='duration')  
    [this is where I need help. using 'duration' or F object doesn't help]

    objs = Model.Objects.filter(q1 & q2)
```

I believe I'm on wrong track. There must be some standard way to accomplish this.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Rakesh

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by `using 'duration' or F object doesn't help` ? how is `duration` being computed?

Comment: This is exactly the question. duration is a column name. How do I get 'duration' while doing arithmetic in Q object. I need an SQL query akin to this.  SELECT * from Model WHERE arrival_date = current_date and arrival_time + duration > current_time